# Denominator negative, numerator negative but sign of fraction not positive?

Tags: assumptions

I am trying to determine the sign of a fraction by determining the sign of the denominator and the numerator seperately using some parametric assumptions (`ass6`):

```
Assuming[ass6, TrueQ[Simplify[Denominator[detHesse] < 0]]]
```

which returns `True` and

```
Assuming[ass6, TrueQ[Simplify[Numerator[detHesse] < 0]]]
```

also returning `True`. However,

```
Assuming[ass6, TrueQ[Simplify[detHesse > 0]]]
```

returns `False`.

What am I missing? Thank you guys

Comment: For a full answer can you post a self-contained code? Need to have the ass6 and detHesse. or just ass6 would probably be enough.

Comment: Have you tried using `FullSimplify` rather than `Simplify`?

Comment: Thank you @VahagnTumanyan and @BobHanlon. As @mikado pointed out the problem is that `Simplify[detHesse > 0]` doesn't simplify to `True`explicitly, so that `TrueQ`returns `False`. I realized that the problem arises because I use `Reduce` in the definition of `ass6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help

> Unless expr is manifestly True, TrueQ[expr] effectively assumes that
>   expr is False.

So expressions that do not simplify to `True` will not necessarily return 
true even if they are.

```
eqns = {Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x]^2 == 1, x Gamma[x] == Gamma[x + 1]};

TrueQ /@ eqns
(* {False, False} *)

TrueQ[Simplify[#]] & /@ eqns
(* {True, False} *)

TrueQ[FullSimplify[#]] & /@ eqns
(* {True, True} *)
```

This behaviour is common to functions whose name ends in `Q`

Comment: Thanks @mikado, that seems to be exactly the issue. In fact, I realized that the problem in my case seems to be that I use Reduce on my set of assumptions which suggests that Reduce does not what I thought it does.